# Lazy loading a @Forumla field inside an @Ebedded object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have an @Embedded object with @Formula field to which I've added   @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY), and I'm using byte code enhancement. When the @Formula is used in an actual @Entity, it pays attention to the lazy loading. Doesn't seem to when the @Formula is part an @Embedded. Any way to make that happen? Am I missing something?

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  private Bar bar;


  @Embedded
  public Bar getBar () {

    return ;
  }

  public void setBar (Bar bar) {

    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

@Embeddable
public class Bar {

  private int bazzCount;

  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Formula("(select count(*) from bazzes)")
  public int getBazzCount () {

    return bazzCount;
  }

  public void setBazzCount (int bazzCount) {

    this.bazzCount = bazzCount;
  }
}
```